# Удалить запись из sql таблицы при нажатии на ссылку и изменение статуса отправки формы с чекбоксами

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здравствуйте, друзья. Никак не могу сообразить как мне удалять по одной записи из таблицы по id при нажатии на кнопку "Удалить" `<td><a href=''>Удалить <?=$id?> </a>`

А также нужно с помощью выбранных чекбоксов и отправки формы изменять в базе значение ячейки с 0 на 1. `<td><?php if ($data['is_done'] == 0){echo "не сделано";}else{ echo "СДЕЛАНО";} ?></td>`.

```
 <?php
include "config.php";
$sql= "SELECT * FROM tasks";
$add = $dbh->query($sql);
$row = 1;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="700px">
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>Описание</td>
                <td>Статус</td>
                <td>Дата создания</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <?php while($data = $add->fetch()){ ?>

                <td><?php $id = $data['id']; echo $id;?></td>

                <td><?=$data['description'];?></td>

                <td><?php if ($data['is_done'] == 0){echo "не сделано";}else{ echo "СДЕЛАНО";} ?></td>

                <td><?=$data['date_added'];?></td>

                <td><a href=''>Удалить <?=$id?> </a>



                </td>

                <td>                    
                    <form>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="welldone" name="done" value="done">
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr></tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
                    <button type="submit">Отметить выделенные как "сделано"</button>
                    </form>

<form  method="post" action ="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="descript" placeholder="Введите описание">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" >
</form>

<?php

$sqladd="INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `description`, `is_done`, `date_added`) VALUES (NULL, :descript, '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

                    //$sqldelete="DELETE FROM `homework2`.`tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`id` = $id";
                    //$newdelete=$dbh->prepare($sqldelete);
                    //$newdelete->execute(); 

if (isset($_POST['descript']))
{
    $descript=$_POST['descript'];

    $newadd=$dbh->prepare($sqladd);
    $newadd->bindValue(':descript', $descript);
    $newadd->execute();

    if ($newadd = 'true')
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Запись добавлена в список дел!");</script>';
        header("Location: index.php");

    }else
        {
             echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Запись НЕ добавлена в список дел! Попробуйте еще");</script>';
        }
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почему вы при изменении descript пишите нормальный запрос, а при удалении - нет? В чём фишка писать плохо и хорошо в одном коде?

Answer (score -1):

По ссылке только методом GET

```
<a href="?delete=<?=$id?>">Удалить <?=$id?> </a>

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = ?')->execute([$_GET['delete']]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, делал что-то подобное но лимит не ставил, поэтому наверное все удалялось. По изменению статусов по чекбоксам не подскажите?